# Why is the output of ls is like this?

Tags: command-line, shell

I am using Mac OS X Snow Leopard and when I type

```
ls c *
```

this is what I get in my terminal:

```
clock:
PSD               demo.html         jquery.tzineClock script.js         styles.css

clock2:

clojure-presentations:
Clojure-1up.pdf            ClojureInTheField-1up.pdf  license.html
Clojure-4up.pdf            README
ClojureForRubyists-1up.pdf keynote

coffee-script:
Cakefile      README        bin           examples      index.html    package.json  test
LICENSE       Rakefile      documentation extras        lib           src           vendor
```

By default I am using Bash.

Comment: Now I realize that there was a space between c and star. And that caused all this trouble. Anyways learned something new.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just drilling into all the directories that match on c*, which can be cured by saying

```
ls -d c*
```

instead.

Answer (score 2):

ls c * lists the file c and all files/directories * 
One can configure the shell to stop at once, because c does not exist
while you meant c*

Answer (score 1):

That's how it shows the contents of directories. Did you mean to add `-d`?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like sometrhing has aliases ls to ls -R.

What is the result of 
alias ls

Fix is probably

```
alias ls=
```

Comment: No​, not this​.